# Unexpected token 'BillingState'

Tags: account

### My Code is:

```
public with sharing class AccountTriggerHandler {
    public static List<Account> CreateAccounts(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE ShippingState == BillingState];
    }
}
```

---

why there is an error

> "unexpected token BillingState"?

The requirement is:

> Create an Apex class named AccountTriggerHandler that contains a
>   public static method called CreateAccounts to accept the List of
>   Account objects For each Account record, before saving, ensure that
>   the ShippingState field has the same value as the BillingState field

Answer (score 1):

You need to **ensure that the ShippingState field has the same value as the BillingState field** before records are saved. You need to invoke it in before insert context and assign ***BillingState*** to ***ShippingState***

**Trigger:**

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert) {

    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert)
        AccountTriggerHandler.CreateAccounts(Trigger.new);

}
```

**AccountTriggerHandler:**

```
public class AccountTriggerHandler {

    public static void CreateAccounts(List<Account> accounts) {
        for(Account acc : accounts) {
            acc.ShippingState = acc.BillingState;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It works now, thank you!

Comment: WC :=). It is a good practice to close the question by accepting the answer which solved your issue. Pls go through https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

As far as this requirement is concerned, you are going a little bit off direction, the requirement says to accept a List of Accounts and not return List of Accounts and ensure that the ShippingState field has the same value as the BillingState field. So you will have to create a method

- Which accepts list of Account records.
- Loop through the records and assign `ShippingState` equal to `BillingState`

And regarding the things you are trying, unfortunately you cannot do field to field comparison in salesforce i.e. you cannot compare values of `BillingState` and `ShippingState`. For such kind of scenarios, you can refer salesforce help documentation i.e. [Field to field comparison in an SOQL WHERE clause](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331053&type=1&mode=1) wherein you will have to create a `boolean` formula field (where formula will be `ShippingState=BillingState`) and query for those records where this `boolean` field is `true`.

And if you want to compare values without using a new `formula` field, you can do that in Apex which you cannot do in `SOQL`

```
for(Account acc: lstAccount){
    if(acc.ShippingState==acc.BillingState){
        //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

And just a note about the the bind variable, you should use `:` in the SOQL query when using bind variables. You can check this [Using Apex Variables in SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm) for further help on this topic. Also, you should be using `=` instead of `==` in the SOQL query. Example of using variables in Apex

```
string sBillingState='SE';
[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE ShippingState =:sBillingState];
```

Comment: https://na112.salesforce.com/_ui/common/apex/debug/ApexCSIPage    Thank you! But the error still exist:    unexpected token 'BillingState'

Comment: -1 vote for this query will not work. You cannot compare two fields in where clause.

Comment: Well, I assumed `BillingState` as a variable, my initial answer was based on that assumption.

Comment: Hey, According to your assumption, I assum BillingState as a variable, so I revised my code as:--------public with sharing class AccountTriggerHandler {
    public static List<Account> CreateAccounts(String BillingState){
       List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();
        String BillingState;
 for(Account acc: lstAccount){  if(acc.ShippingState==acc.BillingState){return lstAccount; } } }}   still wrong. Can you check what is it?

Comment: If you assumed BillingState as variable, then your query should be `[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE ShippingState =:BillingState];`

Comment: Now I my code is --public class AccountTriggerHandler {
    public static List<Account> CreateAccounts(String BillingState){  
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE ShippingState =:BillingState];       
    }
}-But stil unepected token 'BillingState'. So I am confused how to declare the variable 'BillingState'.

Comment: Change the variable name `BillingState` to something else like `sBillingState` and then your query would be `[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE ShippingState =:sBillingState];`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you are looking to query account where ShippingState and BillingState are equals. 
In this scenario, you can create a formula field, the return type for formula field will be boolean/Checkbox. Formula should be ShippingState = BillingState.

This formula field will return you either true or false.

You can use this formula field in your query

```
public with sharing class AccountTriggerHandler {
    public static List<Account> CreateAccounts(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE CustomforMulaField__c = true];
    }
}
```

Hope it answer your question

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you tell me how to create this formula field 'CustomforMulaField__c' where where ShippingState and BillingState are equals?

Comment: N.B. query will not use an index and if set of Accounts in database is large time out; however, use of formula field for this use case works well for most orgs