# Error Message On Trailhead Module :https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_basics_dotnet/execution_context

Tags: trigger

Afer finishing writing code, the error msg displayed as:

> "There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this
>   assessment check from completing: System.DmlException: Insert failed.
>   First exception on row 0; first error:
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, AccountTrigger: execution of
>   BeforeInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: DML statement cannot
>   operate on trigger.new or trigger.old
>   Class.AccountTriggerHandler.CreateAccounts: line 11, column 1
>   Trigger.AccountTrigger: line 3, column 1: []";

My code link is https://na112.salesforce.com/_ui/common/apex/debug/ApexCSIPage

What is it?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to insert/update/delete on Trigger.new or Trigger.old which you can't do, as the error says. Can't see your code either, as that would mean logging in to your Salesforce org.

Comment: trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
        AccountTriggerHandler.CreateAccounts(Trigger.New);
    }
}

Comment: Answered it in [your  question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278847/unexpected-token-billingstate/278957#278957)